# Admin-graphql - Create private metafield on shopify

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify, metadata

How do I create a private metafield on Shopify using Admin-graphql? In their docs, they have given example for retrieving a private metafield by its ID(ref: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/queries/privateMetafield#section-examples), do you have any example for creating private metafield using Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node, it has support for GraphQL calls. https://insomnia.rest/ has great GraphQL support, with field hinting, query eval etc.

An example of creating a product with a private metafield:

```
mutation productCreate($input: ProductInput!, $namespace: String!) {
    productCreate(input: $input) {
        product {
            id
            bufferProductId: privateMetafield(
                key: "your_field_key"
                namespace: $namespace
            ) {
                value
            }
            tags
            variants(first: 10) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        sku
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        userErrors {
            field
            message
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass these variables to the GraphQL query:

```
{
    "input": {
        "title": "Your product name",
        "options": [
            "Size",
            "Colour"
        ],
        "handle": "your-product-name",
        "tags": [
            "Product tag"
        ],
        "vendor": "Lauri's sportin' goods",
        "variants": [
            {
                "sku": "ABC123XL",
                "options": [
                    "Large",
                    "Blue"
                ]
            },
            {
                "sku": "ABC123L",
                "options": [
                    "Large",
                    "Yellow"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "privateMetafields": [
            {
                "key": "your_field_key",
                "namespace": "your_namespace",
                "valueInput": {
                    "value": "Your field value",
                    "valueType": "STRING"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "namespace": "your_namespace"
}
```

This will return the private metafield value in the product creation response.
A few things that make private metafields different from public ones:

- you can add / update the private metafield over and over using ProductUpdate, whereas
- you can only access the private metafields through GraphQL. AFAIK, they're not visible anywhere in the Shopify Admin, or using the REST API.
- even with GraphQL, those fields will be visible *only to the API key that created them.* So, you won't see them with another Shopify App.

You can use [these field types](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-04/enums/PrivateMetafieldValueType) to set the private metafield values.